# git checkout lost files

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am new to git so can you please suggest me how can I resolve this

```
I was on branch name v1.2.3-build2

> git status
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/v1.2.3-build2'.

Changes to be committed:
new file:   Project/Modules/Debug/Debug.swift
.....

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified ....

> git:(v1.2.3-build2) ✗ git checkout -b v1.2.3-debug


> A Project/Modules/Debug/Debug.swift
> M Project/Modules/Home/Home.swift
> ....

Switched to a new branch 'v1.2.3-debug'
> git push --set-upstream origin v1.2.3-debug
```

But I am not able to find the code on git anymore even I try git reset and git log nothing work.

Comment: The log seems fine. What do you mean by "not able to find the code"?

Comment: I am unable to find file 'Debug.swift' i checked every branch, and moreover it's not on my pc anymore deleted from my pc as well @ElpieKay

Comment: I don't see there that you _committed_. Did you?

Comment: @eftshift0 nope

Comment: Try `git fsck --lost-found`. There would be some dangling blobs whose backups you can find under `.git/lost-found/other`. Open and see if any of them contains the contents of `Debug.swift`. It any does, copy the file to  `Project/Modules/Debug/Debug.swift`.

Comment: i tried but no luck, i checked each dangling blob anyway thanks for help

Comment: If you staged and committed everything and `Debug,swift` is still not in there check your .gitignore. Are you maybe using a template .gitignore that contains restrictions for XCode debugging information that are now automagically going wild?